# Remove unused CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I identify and eliminate unused CSS styles from my bloated stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574136/how-do-i-identify-and-eliminate-unused-css-styles-from-my-bloated-stylesheet)

I have a html page and a huge CSS file that has about 900 style entries. I tried to clean it with Dust-Me and it found about 700 unused selectors. So, I think I can just go crazy removing these selectors from the list manually. Is there a way to remove them automatically?

Answer (score 8):

Identifying unused CSS selectors using tools such as Dust-Me have some
degree of error associated with them. For example, does it reliably identify a style
referenced in dynamically created HTML - as might be done through JavaScript?
The creators of Dust-Me may have been aware of this sort of pitfall and
are actually protecting you by not offering to clean-up your CSS files.

The problem with identifying unused elements is that one has to make the
assumption that because a usage was not found the element is unused. This is
often a poor assumption. The site may not have been fully spidered resulting in 
missing references. Or, a dynamically created reference was not "visible" to the tool. In either case, automatically removing a CSS selector because some tool did not find
a reference to it is a very large leap of faith - one that most likely will get you into
trouble.

I recommend taking their generated list and doing the job by hand – very carefully!