# How to remove unnecessary css elements and js methods in Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for my Rails 4 app with asset_pipeline. asset_pipeline automatically concatenate all js and css files into one each.

However, the files are quite large (~120K) and take a long time to load. Is there a way to automatically remove css elements and js methods that are not used in my app from the base files?

Answer (score 1):

From the accepted answer on [How do I identify and eliminate unused CSS styles from my bloated stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574136/how-do-i-identify-and-eliminate-unused-css-styles-from-my-bloated-stylesheet) you could try:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10704/

Credit to [Steve Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75525/steve-fenton)

Remember also that you should be gzipping the css & JS files at the server level, so the actual file size will be substantially less than 120 K

Good luck!